# Spring xd yarn port requirements

Tags: spring-xd

I am configuring Spring xd on yarn.

For data import export and processing with spring xd on yarn which all ports are needed to  open for data nodes inside cluster.

I can see port for redis , rabbit , database which we are going to run next go cluster.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The XD Admin needs Redis, the database connection and Zookeeper but that's probably already in your cluster. You only need Rabbit port if you use Rabbit as the transport.

The XD Containers only need Zookeeper plus the database if you run batch jobs. In addition to these, you would need additional ports only if the modules you launch requires them, like Redis for any counters, the Mongo sink or the GemFire source etc.

Comment: Hello Thomas , for example we run spark streaming job on yarn via spring xd. Which all ports will be needed for this. Another example is if we run sqoop job via spring xd on yarn which all ports are needed by this.